# JDT - How to get ICompilationUnit from CompilationUnit

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

this is my code.
I'm making a CompilationUnit there

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setEnvironment(getProjectJars(), getSrcPaths(), null, true);

parser.setSource(IOUtils.toCharArray(new FileInputStream(MY_SRC_FILE)));
parser.setUnitName(MY_SRC_FILE.getAbsolutePath());

CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

How to get ICompilationUnit from CompilationUnit which has been made from source? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath path = Path.fromOSString(source.getAbsolutePath());
IFile file = workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);
ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = (ICompilationUnit) JavaCore.create(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
ICompilationUnit cu= (ICompilationUnit)compilationUnit.getJavaElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first option is as follows：

```
ICompilationUnit compilationUnit = JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(javaFile);  
types = compilationUnit.getAllTypes();
```

The second option is as follows：

```
IProject project = javaFile.getProject(); 
IJavaProject jProject = JavaCore.create(project); 
if (jProject == null || !jProject.exists()) 
{   
   return null; 
} 
IPackageFragment packageFragment = null; 
try {   
   packageFragment = jProject.findPackageFragment(
                         javaFile.getFullPath().removeLastSegments(1));     
   String unitName = javaFile.getName();    
   ICompilationUnit cu = packageFragment.getCompilationUnit(unitName);  
   return cu; 
} catch (JavaModelException e) {    
return null; 
}
```